Is there a separable extension of degree 21?
Given the field $F= \mathbb{F}_3$ and a transcendental $t$, I am trying to find an intermediate field
$$ F(t^{1/63}) \supset E \supset F(t) $$
where $[F(t^{1/63}): E]= 21$ and the extension is separable, or show that no such extension exists. I suspect the latter is true, the following is my reasoning by contradiction:
Since the composite of separable extensions is separable, and since $F(t^{1/63})/F(t)$ is not separable, $E/F(t)$ cannot be separable. Since $3$ is prime, and this extension is algebraic, it must be a simple extension, hence
$$E= F(t)(\alpha)$$
where $\alpha$ is a root of an polynomial of the form
$$x^3 + ax^2+bx+ c$$
Since this extension is inseparable, the formal derivative of this polynomial must be $0$, hence $$a=b=0$$
so $\alpha=c^{1/3}$ where $c\in F(t)$. Let $p\in F[X]$ be such that
$$c= p(t)$$
Then
$$E= F(t)(p(t)^{1/3}) = F(t)(p(t^{1/3}))$$
Now here's the fun part, we can write
$$\alpha = p(t^{1/3}) = a+ bt^{1/3} + ct^{2/3} $$
Where $a,b,c\in F(t)$, and since $a\in F(t)(\alpha)$ we get
$$\beta = bt^{1/3} + ct^{2/3} \in F(t)(\alpha)$$
Squaring this we get
$$\beta^2 = tc^2t^{1/3} + b^2t^{2/3} \in F(t)(\alpha)$$
Now if $\beta$ is not a scalar (in $F(t)$) multiple of $\beta^2$ then we can take a linear combination of these to get
$$t^{1/3}\in F(t)(\alpha) $$
Which leads to a contradiction (which I will explain at the end)
If $\beta^2 = d\beta$ for some $d\in F(t)$ then diving by $\beta$ yields $\beta\in F(t)$ which means $\alpha\in F(t)$, which means the extension was trivial, a contradiction since we assumed it has degree 3. Thus $$t^{1/3}\in F(t)(\alpha)$$
but then $$F(t^{1/63}) = F(t^{1/3})(t^{1/63})$$
And the minimal polynomial of $t^{1/63}$ over $F(t^{1/3})$ is
$$x^{21} - t^{1/3} $$
Which is not separable, a contradiction. Hence, there is no intermediate field $E$ s.t. $F(t^{1/63})/E$ is separable and $[F(t^{1/63}):E] = 21$. The sheer length of this proof makes me a bit weary that I made a mistake, and it seems like the kind of statement that has a shorter proof. Is my proof correct, and is there a simpler way to do it? (If my proof is not correct, please do not give a counterexample, in such a case where a counterexample exists, I want to find it myself)

I don't know if your way is correct, but there is a very simple proof: $t^{1/9}$ must be separable over $E$, but its minimal polynomial over $F(t)$ is $(X-t^{1/9})^9$. Hence $t^{1/9} \in E$ and $[E : F(t)] \geqslant 9$, a contradiction.

Your proof seems correct to me. As mentioned in the comments, the probably shortest proof considers $t^{1/9}$. Since it has degree $9$ over $\mathbb F_3(t)$, it can't be in $E$. On the other hand, it's minimal polynomial is $(X-t^{1/9})^9$, so $E(t^{1/9})/E$ can't be separated.

Here is another approach, using some more general theory: The separable degree of a field extension $K\subset L$ is defined as $$[L:K]_s=|\operatorname{Hom}_K(L,\overline K)|,$$ where $\overline K$ is an algebraic closure of $K$. One can show that this divides $[L:K]$ (if the extension is finite), and that the field extension is separable if and only if $[L:K]_s=[L:K]$. Finally, the separable degree behaves multiplicatively in field towers: If $K\subset L\subset M$ are fields, then $$[M:K]_s=[M:L]_s\cdot[L:K]_s.$$

So let's compute the separable degree of $\mathbb F_3(t^{1/63})/\mathbb F_3(t)$. Any $\mathbb F_3(t)$-linear map $\mathbb F_3(t^{1/63})\to\overline{\mathbb F_3(t)}$ must map $t^{1/63}$ to another $63$rd root of $t$, that is, to an element of the form $\zeta t^{1/63}$, where $\zeta$ is a $63$rd root of unity. Conversely, any such root of unity defines a unique morphism. Therefore, $$[\mathbb F_3(t^{1/63}):\mathbb F_3(t)]_s=|\{\zeta\in\overline{\mathbb F_3}\mid \zeta^{63}=1\}|.$$ But these are exactly the zeros of $X^{63}-1=(X^7-1)^9$ in $\overline{\mathbb F_3}$. Since $X^7-1$ doesn't have any double roots (the formal derivative is $X^6$), we conclude that $[\mathbb F_3(t^{1/63}):\mathbb F_3(t)]_s=7$.

Now let $\mathbb F_3(t^{1/63})/E/\mathbb F_3(t)$ be any intermediate field, then $$7=[\mathbb F_3(t^{1/63}):\mathbb F_3(t)]_s=[\mathbb F_3(t^{1/63}):E]_s\cdot[E:\mathbb F_3(t)]_s,$$ so $[\mathbb F_3(t^{1/63}):E]_s=1$ or $7$. Therefore the only possible (non-trivial)  sbfields such that $\mathbb F_3(t^{1/63})/E$ is separable have degree $7$.

Wow, a beautiful answer! Thank you. The conclusion I want to actually reach is precisely your final conclusion, that the only possible degree for a severable extension is 7, but I go about it by excluding individual degrees which divide 63, the only really tricky of which is 21, but this is a nice elegant catch all. Is this a common use for the severability degree? and why does choosing a 63rd root of unity uniquely determine a morphism?

That is indeed exactly the point of the sebarability degree: measuring "how much" of the extension is separable. For your other question: A field morphism is determined by its values on a generating set, since we can extend linearly: Once you fix the image of $t^{1/63}$, call it $a$, then any element $\sum x_i(t^{1/63})^i$ has to map to $\sum x_ia^i$.
